# como puedo realizar este metodo

Tags: java, bluej

me encargaron un programa que ya casi termino pero me quede estancado en la elaboración de un método que es el siguiente,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo me gustaría saber como realizar ese método que sume a cada ocurrencia el valor de su posición para que quede como este ejemplo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(edit)Aquí esta el código que llevo hasta ahora, una disculpa, pensé que ya lo había puesto anteriormente.
mi problema esta en el método sumaVector, no se me ocurre como sumar a la ocurrencia del vector el valor de su posición.

```
public class Vector
{
    static Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static double [] cargadatos(double [] Vector)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Vector.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" Ingresa el valor de la posicion ");
            Vector[i]= lector.nextDouble();
        }
        return Vector;
    }    
    public static void muestraVector(double [] Vector)
    {
        System.out.println("\nVector Original:");
        for(int i = 0; i < Vector.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(Vector[i] + " ");
        }
    }    
    public static void sumaVector (double [] Vector)
    {
        System.out.println("\nVector modificado ");
        for(int i = 0; i < Vector.length; i++)
        {
            //
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        double [] Vector;
        int tam = 1;
        while(tam > 0)
        {
            System.out.print("\nTamaño del vector ");
            tam = lector.nextInt();
            if(tam > 0)
            {
                Vector = new double[tam];
                Vector = cargadatos(Vector);
                muestraVector(Vector);
                sumaVector(Vector);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: una disculpa, pense que si habia puesto mi codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes sumar el valor de la posición al valor de cada posición y retornar el vector, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public static double[] sumaVector (double [] Vector)
{
    System.out.println("\nVector modificado ");
    for(int i = 0; i < Vector.length; i++)
    {
        Vector[i] += i;
    }

    return Vector;
}
```

Comment: me sirvió mucho esto!, y perdón por la molestia pero como puedo hacer para que muestre este vector modificado?

Comment: ya lo resolví, muchas gracias!.

Comment: Que bien, para eso estamos. :D

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes crear un nuevo vector de dobles y retornarlo después de llenarlo en el ciclo, tambien debes poner como valor de retorno un `vector de dobles`:

```
public static double[] sumaVector (double [] Vector)
{
    double[] vectorResultado = new double[Vector.length];
    System.out.println("\nVector modificado ");
    for(int i = 0; i < Vector.length; i++)
    {
        /*
          Asignamos a ese espacio la suma entre el contenido del
          vector original e i.
        */
        vectorResultado[i] = Vector[i] + i;
    }

    //Devolvemos el vector transformado
    return vectorResultado;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Riven, me ayudaste mucho tambien!.